# Apache Cassandra 2.1.6 Not Binding to port 9042

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have added the port to Iptables for Input, Forward and Output, still no luck

[image: The error I got]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have something already running on 9042? What does netstat -alnp | grep 9042 show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that an earlier instance was still binding to the port with its process.
netstat -alnp | grep 9042  - This showed the process id
kill -KILL  - this killed it

Cassandra started successfully